# AEM tags not getting displayed in the correct order

Tags: aem

I have written a script that generates some AEM tags and pushes it into the crx. The tags work perfectly.

Under `cq:tags`

[image]

Now I read these tags and display it as a dropdown in my dialog.

[image]

The order of these tags somehow gets jumbled on its own. Does anyone know why does this happen and what is the fix?

Cheers!

Comment: When you created the tags, did you create them in the order 'h3, h1, h2'?  i believe items return in the order in which they were created.  however, the dialog display may be doing a sort by name which is absent from your dropdown.

Comment: The tags are generated and pushed in the order h1, h2, h3. The value of each tag is h1, h2, h3 and so on.. whereas the title is H1, H2, H3.. and so on.

Comment: can you post the code which reads the tags and displays it in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

What is the node type of your heading node?  The type will govern whether it is orderable.  Validate that your tags are created as `jcr:primaryType` = `cq:Tag` and that `sling:resourceType` = `cq/tagging/components/tag`.

See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2513656 for more details.  You may want to check JCR specs on the node type you are using.

- JCR 2.0: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/23_Orderable_Child_Nodes.html
- JCR 1.0: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/1.0/4.4_Orderable_Child_Nodes.html